# Swapping of values within a cell in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, cell

This i just a small basic doubt where I am stuck. How do we swap values within a cell using VBA?

```
For Example
If the value in the cell is 0080 I want it to be swapped to 8000
or if the value is 1567 it should be swapped to 6715
```

Please if someone could help

Comment: What have you done so far - show us your attempts so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Select a cell and:

```
Sub swap()
    With ActiveCell
        .Value = Right(.Value, 2) & Left(.Value, 2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`WS.Range("A5").Value = Right$(WS.Range("A5").Value, 2) & left$(WS.Range("A5").Value, 2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Replace()
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="0080^t", Replacement:="8000^t", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    Cells.Replace What:="0080", Replacement:="8000", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

It works on my Excel. Thank you.